# wcf service (class) level OperationBehavior

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

Currently for all the wcf operations I have to put OperationBehavior attribute (for impersonation) on top of each method.

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

Putting it for every method seems like a waste of time. What I need is eliminating the necessity of applying behavior to all available operations. Is there a way to put this attribute   class level so that it affects all the methods in that service class?

Answer (score 4):

Create your own Attribute that implements `IServiceBehavior` and apply the correct operation behavior to all available operations:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AllowImpersonationAttribtute : Attribute, IServiceBehaviour
{
  void IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription desc, ServiceHostBase host)
  {
    var operations = desc.Endpoints.SelectMany(e => e.Contract.Operations);
    foreach (var operation in operations)
    {
      operation.Behaviors.Add(new OperationBehaviorAttribute{Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed});
    }
  }
  ... // remaining methods empty
}
```

Comment: hi rich, i dont need to implement any attributes. what i need is eliminating the necessity of applying behavior to all available operations.

Comment: @archstanton See update for intended usage. Just add the above attribute to your service and all operations will get the allow impersonation behavior.

Comment: unfortunatelly it didnt help. it says "The service operation 'someMethod' that belongs to the contract with the 'ISomeService' name and the 'http://tempuri.org/' namespace does not allow impersonation"

Comment: btw i got this error on browsing to svc file in iis. somehow attribute is not applied.

Comment: @archstanton Can you debug your code and ensure that the code is run? And that all the operations that you expect to be found are found?

Comment: ok here is the situation: in web config I have <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />. when it is false then it works, otherwise fails. it seems impersonation is needed prior to behavior dispatching.

Comment: @rich.okelly It's worth mentioning 'why' - that the default impersonation option for operations assigned by wcf is 'ImpersonationOption.NotAllowed, meaning he'll be annotating his operations anyways (in addition to in the config file), further vindicating your handy solution :). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649252.aspx